# Spring Boot App cannot connect to PostgreSQL container

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to deploy and run my Spring Boot App  with docker compose, but always getting the exception during Spring Boot contextLoads() method test:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mtab-db

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://mtab-db:5432/dev_mtab_db
spring.datasource.username=noname
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ENV BOT_NAME=somebot
ENV BOT_TOKEN=sometoken
ENV BOT_DB_USERNAME=noname
ENV BOT_DB_PASSWORD=password
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.datasource.password=${BOT_DB_PASSWORD}", "-Dbot.username=${BOT_NAME}", "-Dbot.token=${BOT_TOKEN}", "-Dspring.datasource.username=${BOT_DB_USERNAME}", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mtab-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'dev_mtab_db'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'noname'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE  # CAP_SYS_NICE
  mtab-bot:
    depends_on:
      - mtab-db
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      BOT_NAME: ${BOT_NAME}
      BOT_TOKEN: ${BOT_TOKEN}
      BOT_DB_USERNAME: ${BOT_DB_USERNAME}
      BOT_DB_PASSWORD: ${BOT_DB_PASSWORD}
    restart: on-failure
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pull new changes
git pull

# Prepare Jar
mvn clean
mvn package

# Ensure, that docker-compose stopped
docker-compose stop

# Add environment variables
export BOT_NAME=$1
export BOT_TOKEN=$2
export BOT_DB_USERNAME='noname'
export BOT_DB_PASSWORD='password'

# Start new deployment
docker-compose up --build -d
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: The issue might be that your bot tries to connect before the database is ready. `depends_on` only waits for the database container to be started. Can you try starting the database first by `docker-compose up -d mtab-db`. Then wait a bit and do `docker-compose up -d` to bring up the bot.

Comment: This all looks correct to me.  You should be using the container name and not localhost.  If the database hadn't started yet, you would get a different error, not host not found.  Maybe you should try adding another container on which you could run psql manually to try to debug this?

Comment: @aryaguzov Check your db container logs. I'm 99% sure it is dead => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/d833f3d057dc558ac6328d509f76b8ac You can start your db container with console attached to see the logs on screen: `docker-compose up mtab-db`

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you for helping me. I checked the db container logs and found an issue. Everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: @Zeitounator my bad, I wasn’t attentive enough to remember OP was using docker compose